# how to multiselect images from ImageGallery

Tags: android, image-gallery

I need help regarding selecting multiple images from the image gallery.

Well I want to implement the image Gallery in my application and i want is when i long Press on the Image gallery it would open the image gallery for me to multiple selection of the images.

Can anybody give me some guidelines and tutorials to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: create your custom gallery using gridview. There you can set listeners to achieve the same

Comment: can u add some tutorials for this please